# How to access a device that has invalid SSL certificate from linux mint/debian?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, firefox, debian, linux-mint

I have several devices that have invalid SSL certificates, mostly old routers,iDRAC,iLO etc.
It now appears to be impossible to access these devices via Chrome and Firefox.
In the past I have been able to add exceptions to access these devices, but I no longer seem to get the options.

Now I understand fully that these devices should be upgraded and I know there are very big risks when ignoring certificate errors, so please do not put a ton of replies telling me to upgrade, as this is not always possible, some of these devices do not any any upgrades available! also how do you upgrade a device that can be upgraded if you cant access it in the first place?

So the question is, is it possible to tell Chrome or Firefox to ignore all SSL/Certificate errors (like invalid certificate or incorrect SSL version), or is there an alternative browser that will work in there place that still allows things like javascript etc to run.  I have tried a few browsers in the falcon/surf/hv3 but none of these work.

I cant find any method for the latest versions of chrome and the only thing I could find for firefox was 'security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling' and that didn't seem to make any difference :(
I would prefer to use my current install rather than creating a VM and running a totally outdated OS, which also creates problems with SSH and VPN access.

As request, example of error accessing old draytek router via firefox, no option given to bypass:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to IP-ADDR.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Chrome error when trying to access HP iLO, get option to ignore, but then get :

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at https://IP-ADDR/login.htm might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT
```

But in general looking to be able to access sites that chrome & firefox have decided in the last year or so that I am incapable of deciding if **I** trust the site (emphases on the 'I').

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "invalid" certificate. There are many validation problems where you can simply add an exception and it is unclear what specific problems there are in your case. Are you even sure this is a certificate problem and not a cipher problem, like that the browser no longer support obsolete and insecure ciphers based on RC4? Hard to tell since you don't even provide the exact error message you get in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these errors do not seem to be related to the certificate at all and can therefore not be solved by ignoring certificate problems. These are not trust problems but these are protocol incompatibility problems.

The problem with HP iLO is likely because the device supports only SSL 3.0 which is insecure for years and thus is not usable in any modern browser and OS. The problem with the Draytek router is not fully clear (there should be more information available in the browser) but it is likely similar, i.e. only SSL 3.0 or some unsupported because insecure cipher like RC4.

One option to deal with these devices is to install some older OS (like Ubuntu 12.04 or even older) in a virtual machine and use the browser from this machine to access the device. And of course note that these devices are long out of support and continued use might cause security risks.